# CVXPY: DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to code a problem solves `B(2,1)` under LMI constraints.

R(2,1)=R0(2,1)+H(2,2)*B(2,1)

Vc is a scalar variable

It keeps getting

### > "DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules."

```py
    import numpy as np
    import cvxpy as cp

    H = np.random.rand(2,2)
    R0 = np.random.rand(2,1)

    B=cp.Variable((2,1), complex=True)  
    Rf=cp.diag(R0+H*B)




    RRf=cp.real(Rf)
    IRf=cp.imag(Rf)


    Vc=cp.Variable()
    Vc2= (Vc**2)


    z=np.zeros((Rf.shape[0],Rf.shape[1]))
    I=np.eye(Rf.shape[0])
    objective3=cp.Minimize(Vc2)

    LMI =cp.bmat( [   
                            [Vc2*I,        RRf,    z,        -IRf],
                            [RRf,          I,      IRf,          z],
                            [z,            IRf,    Vc2*I,        RRf],
                            [-IRf,         z,       RRf,          I]      
                                                                                ]) 
    const1 = LMI  >=0
    const2 = Vc   >=0        

    prob=cp.Problem(objective3,[const1,const2])
    print(prob.is_dcp())   




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQpxh.png
```

Comment: Provided that the objective function is DCP =True and -----
LMI block is DCP=True -----
const1 DCP is = False though ?!

Comment: You have the square of a variable appearing inside the matrix. That is not DCP compliant.

Comment: Thanks for replying! @MichalAdamaszek, I replaced the variable Vc instead of the its square in the LMI block and it returned a valid DCP problem .. unfortunately, the following error appeared:
**Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\reductions\complex2real\complex2real.py", line 146, in canonicalize_expr
    assert all(v is None for v in imag_args)

AssertionError**

Comment: As far as I know to get an LMI you should write ``LMI>>0`` and not ``LMI>=0``. What you did now is just say that all entries are nonnegative, which may explain the error (imaginary parts are nonzero).

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I tried `LMI>>0` but it gives the same **AssertionError**. Can it be because I am using a complex variable? <br/>   I am really stuck with this issue for weeks by now. I am a mechanical engineer not a programmer but this code would be a great help at work.

Comment: I ran your code now and you are right that something is wrong. Perhaps it is a bug in the real/imag operators for complex variables that should be reported to cvxpy. Anyway, it worked for me when I defined the real and imaginary parts separately: ``BR=cp.Variable((2,1))  
BI=cp.Variable((2,1))  
RRf=cp.diag(R0+H@BR)
IRf=cp.diag(H@BI)``

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek You are absolutely right the code works that way but the math doesn't!! But your suggestion was a great help the right way ... THANKS!!!

Comment: You were right in the first place . It should be `LMI>>0` not `LMI >=0` but when you put it `>>` the standard SCS solver doesn't handle the matrix size. So I downloaded the CVXOPT solver and it worked fine till now. I hope no more bugs so I can complete the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @MichalAdamaszek 's help the next code works. 
The problem was that CVXPY is not able to handle .real and .imag function inside the constraints.
So the manipulation needed was to break down the complex varibale `B` into two real variables then combine them after the `.solve` using`B=BR.value+1j*BI.value`
The other mistake in the question was putting the constraint as `LMI>=0`. For SDP `LMI>>0` should be used.
The last thing was to use `CVXOPT` solver instead the standard`SCS` as it can't handle more than 2x2 matrices.
The code proves to be mathmatically correct as it always minimize the residual function

> R(2,1)=R0(2,1)+H(2,2)*B(2,1)

print('The residule',abs(R0+np.matmul(H,B))) approaches 0 every run time.
The correct code:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

H = np.random.rand(2,2)
R0 = np.random.rand(2,1)

BR=cp.Variable((2,1))
BI=cp.Variable((2,1))  




RRf=cp.diag((np.real(R0)+np.real(H)@BR-np.imag(H)@BI))
IRf=cp.diag((np.imag(R0)+np.imag(H)@BR+np.real(H)@BI))

Vc2=cp.Variable()


z=np.zeros((RRf.shape[0],RRf.shape[1]))
I=np.eye(RRf.shape[0])
objective3=cp.Minimize(Vc2)


LMI =cp.bmat( [   
                        [Vc2*I,        RRf,    z,        -IRf],
                        [RRf,          I,      IRf,          z],
                        [z,            IRf,    Vc2*I,        RRf],
                        [-IRf,         z,       RRf,          I]      
                                                                            ]) 
const1 = LMI  >>0



prob=cp.Problem(objective3,[const1])
prob.solve(solver=cp.CVXOPT, kktsolver=cp.ROBUST_KKTSOLVER)
B=BR.value+1j*BI.value

print(abs(B),Vc2.value)
print('The residule',abs(R0+np.matmul(H,B)))
```

Comment: `kktsolver=cp.ROBUST_KKTSOLVER` is important if you want more robust with no errors. It is a slower option though.